# CSRF token not working in a Laravel ajax call

Tags: laravel

I've checked the gizillion answers to this question and for some reason I can't get this to work.

I get the error:

> 401 (Unauthorized)

My route is an api route guarded.

My data:

```
let ajaxMainTemplate = {
  'mainTemplate': mainTemplate,
  'templateId': templateId,
  '_token': accessToken,
}
```

My ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url:`../api/aiMainTemplate/${ajaxData.templateId}`,
    data: {
        _token: ajaxData._token,
        ajaxData
    },
    success: function(response) {
        console.log(response)
    }
})
```

I've tried the above to test based on another response.  I put the token outside of the `ajaxData` object.  I get the same error.  I've also attempted:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url:`../api/aiMainTemplate/${ajaxData.templateId}`,
    headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': ajaxData._token },
    data: ajaxData,
    success: function(response) {
        console.log(response)
    }
})
```

Same.

I've also confirmed the token is there by adding a `console.log`  Any ideas what I'm doing wrong with this?

Comment: When the problem is dued to the csrf token, laravel normally returns 419, not 401. probably the problem is because you are using some api authentication that you haven't fullfiled in the ajax post

Comment: Ah excellent catch.  @Gamopo

Comment: As mentioned, 401 is not a token issue, so maybe this is something else, but you are passing the token using `ajaxData`, but the variable is actually `ajaxMainTemplate`.  Also the structure of the `data` you are passing in the first AJAX example looks wrong, should it just be `data: ajaxMainTemplate`?

Comment: Hi, no the ajax call is in a method and ajaxData is the parameter received.

Answer (score 0):

My url was behind the api protected route so I had to do an ajax call to login into it via ajax.

The credentials are in a variable ajaxData.

```
  $.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/login',
  data: ajaxData,
  success: function(response) {
     shopifyToken = response.success.token;
     getListProducts(shopifyToken);
  }
  });
```

With the shopify token generated from this login it worked.